# MX Record without a static IP

Tags: mx-record, dyndns

There might already be an answer for this, I didn't find one, maybe I'm looking for the wrong thing.

The situation:

- one domain `x.org` which has a dyndns to my non-static home IP
- one domain `y.org` which I want to send emails from and to
- an email server at home

Now, if I understand correctly, I need a MX Record on domain `y.org` in order to manage email. So I forwarded it to my IP at home. But this IP changes obviously, so I'd have to update the MX record every day since I cannot just put in `x.org` in order for it to use the dyndns of domain `x.org`.

My question: Can I somehow utilize the dyndns of `x.org` in the MX record of `y.org`? Is there a better way which I haven't thought of yet?

Comment: On the Y domain put an MX record pointing to an A record on the X domain. the Y domain remains untouched while the dynamic DNS is handled by the X domain.

Comment: @André so I'd put in x.org there, not the IP? Well, my provider doesn't allow for that o.0 any other way?

Comment: On the X domain, you should have an A record like "mail.x.org", on the Y domain put an MX record pointing to "mail.x.org". If your provider doesn't allow it try to add a dot at the end like "mail.x.org.", and it it still doesn't work then change DNS providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the MX record for y.org can point to a DNS entry in x.org e.g. mail.x.org.

You may also want to set up your SPF record

What interface are you using to set up your DNS records?  If it doesn't allow you to set up what you want it may be a limitation of your hosting company's interface.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, my provider (godaddy) doesn't seem to want me to do that. Any other way to work around this issue? Accepting because the question is answered, my problem is not though :D